# Using QT how can I remove the first line in a text file without reading the entire file?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, text

I'm manually logging events from my QT application into a text file.

I'm keeping track of how many lines I write into the text file and when I get over a certain amount I want to start removing the first line.

I shouldn't open and read the entire text file each time I want to remove the first line as the text file becomes large.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::Append)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << timeStamp+typeStamp+" "+message << endl;
    stream.flush();
    file.close();
    LOG_COUNT++;
} else {
    qWarning()<<"Utils::writeToLog - unable to write to log file";
}

if(LOG_COUNT > 5000){
    LOG_COUNT--;

    QFile inputFile(filename);
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       QString line1 = in.readLine();
       QString line2 = in.readLine();

        qWarning()<<"LINE 1 "<<line1;
        qWarning()<<"LINE 2 "<<line2;

        //Replace line 1 & 2 with just line 2?

       inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you write it to file when anyhow you dont want to keep the data? Maybe store it in memory and only write it to file when you know what should go to the file

Comment: Some tricks with file mapping via QFile::map() could be a solution (you can map only part of the file), though I'm not sure if it suits your needs

Answer (score 3):

You can't cut something from the beginning of a file without creating a temp file.

So

- either you read the whole file as a QString / QByteArray, chop the first line* and write it back

or

- you open the file, find the offset of the end of the first line* and close the file, then open it again to write the remaining bytes to a temporary file, and rename it to the original.

[*] Either use QTextStream::readLine() or read bytes until you find a '\n' or '\r', depending on your platform.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think ill just put my logs in a sqlite database then.

Comment: Or i'll just delete the text file and make a new one every 5000 lines, should have thought of that before